# Can I use webhooks to create a log of when certain actions were taken?

Tags: python, heroku

**Problem**: Habitica is a habit-tracking app, but its personal data logs are not as detailed as I want. I want to create a local log of when I mark off habits/todo's in the app. Habitica offers certain webhooks that trigger when habits/todo's are checked off, which seems perfect for what I want, but how do I turn these triggers into a local log? I would like to use Python for this.

**Ideas:** It seems to me that I would need to set up some kind of personal cloud server to receive this data, turn it into a log, and then store it for download. I have previously deployed a Flask app using Heroku, so if this could be done similarly, that would be ideal. However, I don't know much about this, so I would welcome any ideas or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the Habitica webhook as Flask application is a good approach.
Heroku supports Python/Flask very nicely however the file system is ephemeral, hence it gets wiped out at every application restart.

In order to persist data you can look at various options:

- save the file to [AWS S3](https://realpython.com/python-boto3-aws-s3/)
- save the data into a DB (Heroku has a [free plan for PostgreSQL](https://www.heroku.com/pricing))